# Unique decodeability

Tags: information-theory

I am stuck on the question:
"
Prove that any uniquely decodable code from {0,1}* to {0,1}*
necessarily makes some strings longer if it makes some strings shorter.
"
If we can show that the Kraft-McMillan inequality becomes equality, we are done. This is because if a word gets shorter, we add a larger contribution, which implies that another word should get shorter. But I can not figure out how to show this. Is there another way of proving this?

Comment: The pigeon-hole principle is probably useful here.

Comment: If we remove a bit, we create a new codeword, by the unique decodability assumption.
It seems that we need to show that by removing bits from strings with length k, that we 'overflow' the possible spots for strings with length k-1, which are $2^k$. However, the mapping is not 1-1, so we do not know how many code words of length k there are.
Do you understand where I am coming from?

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle#Uses_and_applications The principle can be used to prove that any lossless compression algorithm, provided it makes some inputs smaller (as the name compression suggests), will also make some other inputs larger. Otherwise, the set of all input sequences up to a given length L could be mapped to the (much) smaller set of all sequences of length less than L without collisions (because the compression is lossless), a possibility which the pigeonhole principle excludes.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much!!